# Regex: Match all brackets {} that are not in expressions {0} or {1}

Tags: c#, regex

The title says all, I am trying to match all `{` and `}` but not those included in `{0}` or `{1}`.

Ex: `{asd } {2} asds}w2{1}`

Here, all brackets would match but the last 2.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: c#, but does it really matter?

Comment: @SébastienBelzile Yes. There are different engines that every language implement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edited based on comments:

Here you go:

```
(?!\{[01]\})\{|(?<!\{[01])\}
```

[**Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/dM6tP4/2)

Explanation:

- Match `{` if what follows is not `{0}` or `{1}`.
- Match `}` if what precedes is not `{0` or `{1`.

The matches in the following sample are bolded:

> **{** asd **}** **{** 2 **}** asds **}** w2{1} **{** foo **}** {0} **{** bar **}** **}** **{** **{** **}**

Comment: Thanks but it does not match single brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this regex,

```
(?:\{0\}|\{1\})(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:{|})
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/xF8lN5/3)

OR

```
(?<!0|1)}|{(?!1|0)
```

[DEMO 1](http://regex101.com/r/xF8lN5/4) , [DEMO 2](http://regex101.com/r/xF8lN5/5)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **negative lookhead based regex**:

```
\{(?![12]\})[^}]*\}
```

#### [Online regex Demo](http://regex101.com/r/zT3jH5/1)